# kubernetes nginx ingress controller error

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm using google kubenretes engine. My cluster node version is 1.7. Since that version became unsupported by Google cloud for creating new cluster, I need to use 1.8 or 1.9. 
I'm having issues implimenting my nginx-ingress-controller yaml file at the new versioned cluster but I keep getting this error :

```
     Using build: https://github.com/bprashanth/contrib.git - git-92b2bac when using gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
```

and this error when using quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0

```
     It seems the cluster it is running with Authorization enabled (like RBAC) and there is no permissions for the ingress controller. Please check the configuration
```

here is my my nginx-ingress-controller file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
  labels:
   k8s-app: default-http-backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    k8s-app: default-http-backend
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: default-http-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: default-http-backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: default-http-backend
        # Any image is permissable as long as:
        # 1. It serves a 404 page at /
        # 2. It serves 200 on a /healthz endpoint
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: nginx-ingress-lb
        name: nginx-ingress-lb
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
        name: nginx-ingress-lb
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 10254
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        # use downward API
        env:
          - name: POD_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: POD_NAMESPACE
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        # we expose 18080 to access nginx stats in url /nginx-status
        # this is optional
        - containerPort: 18080
          hostPort: 18080
        args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
        - --nginx-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-ingress-cfg
        - --watch-namespace=production
```

Comment: I'm not in front of my laptop but have a read here:
https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md

basically have a read on RBAC for k8s

Comment: @montatich, you are missing rback permissions.

Answer (score 0):

When running on GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine), you may encounter a ‘permission denied’ error when creating some of these resources. This is a nuance of the way GKE handles RBAC and IAM permissions, and as such you should ‘elevate’ your own privileges to that of a ‘cluster-admin’ before running the above command. If you have already run the above command, you should run them again after elevating your permissions.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
    --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
    --user=$(gcloud config get-value core/account)
```

try hitting this command and then apply the files